# strategy.exit should be wait after strategy.entry

Tags: pine-script

I have a script, this should be called every 5 minute only one time. And after strategy.entry should wait 30 second and check if it can be canceled.

My script looks so, but it does not work, as i wish.

```
 
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)


// create a variable with time of exit
timeLong = 0.0
timeLong := nz(timeLong[1])

msToHours(timeMs) =>
    timeMs / 1000 

isMoreThan() =>
    msToHours(time - timeLong) >= 30

// detect the exit
if strategy.position_size < strategy.position_size[1]
    timeLong := time
    
if (time >  timestamp(2021, 1, 9, 00, 00) )
    strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long, comment="Long")


// === STRATEGY RISK MANAGEMENT EXECUTION ===
// finally, make use of all the earlier values we got prepped
if  isMoreThan()
    strategy.close("Long Entry", comment="Exit")
    timeLong := na
```

Thanks in advance

Gül

Comment: What is wrong with this strategy? I have tested your strategy on BTCUSD,5s and it works as you wish on shallow look https://www.tradingview.com/x/XdMLorIO/

Comment: thanks for your answer, i try it on 1m timeframe, i want to close in 20 second and should wait for new bar then make long again. now it is so: 21:12:06 is long -> 21:13:02 is close long, it should be closed actually on 21:12:26. then 21:13 should be opened a new long

Comment: `time` returns the time of a bar. For 1m bars time will be 21:13:00, 21:14:00, etc. It haven't seconds part. And your strategy calculates only on close of a bar. For intrabar calculations you need set up `calc_on_every_tick` to `true` (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_strategy) and you can try to use `timenow` instead `time` but this will work for RT calculations only.